# jquery 1st click, 2nd click, 1st click, 2nd click

Tags: jquery, css

im trying to figure out, how to add after 1st click one class called active_img to an element and on 2nd click remove the 1st class and add class called reverse_img one and this like place in a loop. So on every odd click, element will get class active_img and on every even click, element will get class reverse_img.
this is what i have in jquery, but it doesnt work, if i add there the 2nd class.

```
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu_img').hasClass('active_img')) {
      $('.menu_img').removeClass('active_img');
    } else {
        $('.menu_img').addClass('active_img');
    }
});
```

html

```
<div class="menu"><img src="menu.svg" class="menu_img" /></div>
```

and scss

```
.menu {
  @include width-height(260px, 220px);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -170px;
  transition: .3s;
  float: left;

    .menu_img {
      width: 60px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      left: 15px;
      margin: 0;
      transition: .3s;
      transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    .active_img {
      animation-name: img;
      animation-duration: .5s;
      -webkit-animation-name: img;
      -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    }
   .reverse_img {
     animation-name: reverse_img;
     animation-duration: .5s;
     -webkit-animation-name: reverse_img;
     -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
   }
 }
.menu:hover {
  background-color: white;
  margin: -110px 0 0 -130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
  .menu_img {
    top: 3px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 70px;
    transition: .3s;
  }
}

@keyframes img {
  0% {}
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes reverse_img {
  0% {}
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
}
```

thx for the answers :D

Comment: have a look at `.toggleClass()` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Please include the HTML, not sure if the issue is the fact that you're not referencing to `$(this)` or is it something else. You can create a working stack snippet by clicking on the `<>` icon in the editor when you [edit] the post

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot, in css i have that if i hover on .menu this something will happen to .menu_img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
    var menuImage = $('.menu_img'),
        newClass = menuImage.hasClass('active_img') ? 'reverse_img' : 'active_img';

        menuImage.removeClass('active_img reverse_img');
        menuImage.addClass(newClass);
    }
});
```

Think that should work. Or...

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
    var menuImage = $('.menu_img');
        menuImage.toggleClass('active_img');
        menuImage.toggleClass('reverse_img');
    }
});
```

If the page always loads initially with appropriate class.

Comment: so i added reverse_img in html to menu_img and the 2nd method works :D thx

Answer (score 2):

Add reverse_img class to your HTML first and use this script:

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
($('.menu_img').toggleClass('active_img'));
($('.menu_img').toggleClass('reverse_img'));
```

});

Comment: so i added reverse_img in html to menu_img and it worked, thx :D

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

This will switch the class on and off every other click

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu_img').toggleClass('active_img');
});
```

Comment: But they say it doesn't work, I think (Your solution is better but it basically does the same thing as the OP's code)

Comment: it does exactly same thing as my code :D but there is less code

Comment: @SenTisso please post more context for your code (html, more js)

Comment: @SenTisso That's why I asked you to add more details to your post :)